# Pipeline for stored procedure dedicated sql pool

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

I am trying to create a pipeline for my stored procedure in dedicated SQL pool. I am getting error Cannot connect to SQL database "" Check the linked service config is correct, and make sure the SQL database firewall allows the integration runtime to access. Logon failed for user ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to access issue. Admin granted relevant access and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the provided user details are correct and the linked service is successfully connected. Add the client IP address in the synapse workspace network to allow access to the client network.

[image]

You can call store procedure in your pipeline using stored procedure activity, lookup activity, copy data activity.

[image]